# How to get a contract SIM card in USA

Tags: usa

I'm now in USA coming from Spain.

I already have an unlocked smartphone.

I would like to have a contract phone. What are my options? Do I need to buy a phone to get a local sim card?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Last time, I walked into a telecom store and they seemed *very* willing to sell me anything they had including SIM cards. What is the *exact* problem you are facing? Have you been rejected and on what grounds?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to get one.  The problem is you have no credit rating in the US and no income in the US.  That basically limits you to pay-as-you-go service.

Comment: I will have income next month

Comment: @biotech It takes time to build your credit rating, though.